# Unix Script - finding duplicate strings in a multiple dat files

Tags: shell, unix, duplicates

Please help me in providing a solution in Unix script for below logic

1. Merge muliple delimited .dat files and place a merged file in a tmp location
2. Duplicates needs to be identified in the merged file based on the primary key fields.i.e. In a single row there may be three to four key fields nees to be considered. The combination of key fields in other rows as well is called as a duplicates. This specific logic needs to be in a editable manner since key fields differs from file to file.
3. Location duplicate output file needs to be placed in a tmp location

For example:

***Original file data (Key fields are ID,Full_Name & Age)***

```
ID|source_code|Full_Name|AGE

123|01|John|20

190|05|Mary|35

123|05|John|20

180|09|John|30

190|100|Seam|20

190|900|Jack|10
```

***Expected output file***

```
123|John|20;2 Occurances;line no 1 & 3
```

Comment: try grep -c -n '123' original-file > expected-output-file

Answer (score 0):

Save following code as `dups.py`, and run `python dups.py < merged_file.dat`

(This is not shell script. You need `python` to run.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for lineno, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, start=0):
    row = line.strip().split('|')
    if len(row) == 4:
        key = '{0[0]}|{0[2]}|{0[3]}'.format(row)
        d[key].append(lineno)

for line in d:
    linenos = d[line]
    if len(linenos) > 1:
        print('{};{} Occurances;line no {}'.format(
            line, len(linenos), ' & '.join(map(str, linenos)))
        )
```

Sample output:

```
$ cat test.dat 
ID|source_code|Full_Name|AGE
123|01|John|20
190|05|Mary|35
123|05|John|20
180|09|John|30
190|100|Seam|20
190|900|Jack|10
$ python dups.py < test.dat
123|John|20;line no 1 & 3
```